# How to save image to gallery

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to make a video recorder and for this I want to save recorded video to gallery but its not saving in gallery instead it is saving is own internal app storage

```
private async void VideoRecorderAsync()
{
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
    {
        _pageDialog.DisplayAlertAsync("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    //var pathFile = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
    //var absolutePath = pathFile.AbsolutePath;

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
    {
        SaveToAlbum = true,
    });

    if (file == null)
        return;

   _pageDialog.DisplayAlertAsync("Video Recorded", "Location: " + file.AlbumPath, "OK");

    file.Dispose();
}
```

I want to save image from mobile gallery.

Comment: You need to save image or video?You need to write platform specific code to save image file or video file. Use dependency injection. App should have write access to the location where you save the files

Comment: I want to save video everything goes fine but instead of gallery video is saving in app storage

Comment: dependency injection or dependency service?

Comment: Dependency service of course